# Redirect traffic from one server to something.cloudapp.net (CNAME)

Tags: domain-name-system, redirect, nat, dnat

Through out North America, we have lots of legacy devices, which sends data to our server which has static IP Address.

Now we are moving to Azure cloud services, and as you know they do not guarantee static ip address. And there is no way to reconfigure all those legacy devices to point them to new ip address, and those devices also does not support DNS (or CNAME) resolution.

I know, the azure cloud service ip address does not change as far as we don't delete the deployment. But it is very likely that it will be deleted (in case if we go and change configuration of all the devices.)

So what we want to do is, redirect the traffic which we get on an ip address to something.cloudapp.net.

I am a just developer, any network (hardware/software) solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of traffic is being sent? Depending on this, it might be suitable to use a proxy on the original address.

Comment: @DavidHoude It is HTTP and HTTPS traffic. Can you please suggest, any such proxy which can forward it to any host name (I am assuming we can configure it to listen on port 80 and 443).

Comment: This can be done with almost any proxy, including Apache's Mod_Proxy. I will try to get a full answer up, but I am limited on time right now. I wish you the best of luck though.

Comment: Thank you very much @DavidHoude I will look into proxy. Thank you once again for showing me right direction.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Forward all TLD requests to another server](http://serverfault.com/questions/590129/forward-all-tld-requests-to-another-server/590132#590132)

Comment: Hi @MichelZ, here I cannot use NAT / iptable approach right? because I think it is easy to redirect traffic from one ip address to another however in this case I need to redirect to a domain name (CNAME record)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's HTTP(S) traffic, a HTTP Proxy will do (Apache mod_proxy, HAProxy, IIS, among others)
If it's other type of traffic, you could NAT it to the other box

Similar to: [Forward all TLD requests to another server](https://serverfault.com/questions/590129/forward-all-tld-requests-to-another-server/590132#590132)

Comment: Can I use NAT or iptables to redirect traffic from IP address to CNAME record hostname? I am exploring mod_proxy's ProxyPass, IIS Application Request Routing (ARR), if you have any information about these it will be great help as well.

Comment: I was able to do it using mod_proxy, seems like HAProxy does not support dns resolution while forwarding traffic.